# How to programmatically detect if a shared library is 64 bit on OSX?

Tags: macos

I am dynamically loading an external library from a 32 bit application. Before loading the library, I want to check if it is 32 bit or not. If it is not 32 bit, then I can notify the user about it. For that, I need a way to programmatically detect the architecture of a shared library on OSX. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply call [dlopen](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with the path to the library and if it fails, it's not compatible. As the documentation states: -

> *If dlopen() fails, it returns a null pointer*